# How to center the text of a thead in a table

Tags: html, css

let's say that i have the following simple table:

```html
    <style type="text/css"> 
    table#one {
    width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
   
    <table id="one">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th colspan="1" >Top Title</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

     <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
     </tr>

    </table>
```

I'd like the "Top Title" to be exactly in the top middle of the table, but i don't know if it's possible to get this effect. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `colspan=3` to ensure that your header spans all of the columns within the table :

```
<th colspan="3">Top Title</th>
```

**Example**
[image]

```css
table#one {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="one">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Top Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. A general rule of thumb is to not use `colspan` unless you specifically want to span over more than a single column (assuming you enough to span across).

Answer (score 1):

Change colspan of 1 to colspan of 3. Your colspan should be the number of `<td>` elements in order to center it.

```html
    <style type="text/css"> 
    table#one {
    width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
   
    <table id="one">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th colspan="3" >Top Title</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

     <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
     </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: thanks! I'll accept this answer as soon as possible :)